Change list output from ConoverTest into a dataframe in R
I need the output generated from the ConoverTest() function from library(DescTools) to generate a dataframe output and not a list.. I need this because I will be running multiple tests and extracting the p.val's and mean rank diff's out of the model output.
This is the current output I get
  
  # fake data
  set.seed(123)
  df <- data.frame(
    Value = rnorm(15),
    STATION = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 5)
  )
  
  # the function
  final.test.result.post <- ConoverTest(df$Value, df$STATION, out.list = TRUE)
  
  final.test.result.post


>   final.test.result.post

# Conover's test of multiple comparisons : holm  

 #   mean.rank.diff   pval    
#B-A           -0.4 0.8738    
#C-A           -5.6 0.1271    
#C-B           -5.2 0.1271    
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1


Is there a way to turn this into a dataframe which has the columns (cross, mean.rank.diff, pval)

It will be much easier to answer your question if you post the output or dput(final.test.result.post)

@FJCC if you run the example data it will create the output.
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
Value = rnorm(15),
STATION = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 5)
)
the function
final.test.result.post <- ConoverTest(df$Value, df$STATION, out.list = TRUE)
final.test.result.post

The pairwiseComparisons package may have already done this.

I'm unable to replicate the p-values you obtain, but you could do something like the following:
df <- final.test.result.post[[1]] |>
    as.data.frame() |>
    tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "cross")

print(df)

  cross mean rank diff pval
1   B-A           -0.8    1
2   C-A            1.4    1
3   C-B            2.2    1


The object structure from ConoverTest() is straight forward enough to extract information from.
If you examine that object with str(final.test.result.post), you'll see the data are stored in the first element as a matrix with both column and row names.
Converting that matrix to a data frame is straight forward. A separate command can convert the row names into a proper column.
Here's a reproducible example:
library(DescTools)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Value = rnorm(15),
  STATION = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 5)
)

# the function
final.test.result.post <- ConoverTest(df$Value, df$STATION, out.list = TRUE)

#Convert the matrix object to a data.frame
results <- as.data.frame(final.test.result.post[1])
#Add row names with column name 'cross'
results$cross <- row.names(results)
#rearrange column names and print
results[, c("cross", "mean.rank.diff", "pval")]

Giving you the result
    cross mean.rank.diff pval
B-A   B-A           -0.8    1
C-A   C-A            1.4    1
C-B   C-B            2.2    1

